# How to Pull Docker Environment Variables from launchSettings.json in C#

Tags: c#, docker, environment-variables

I have a launchSettings.json file and some Docker environmentVariables.
I attempted to pull one of the settings using GetEnvironmentVariable, and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
string strTest = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TESTING");
Console.WriteLine($"Docker Env Test: {strTest}");
```

It isn't returning anything.
I've searched around and the GetEnvironmentVariable seems to be the way to do it, but it's only returning variables from ProgC.

launchSettings.json

```
 {
  "profiles": {
    "ProgC": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "IsDev": "1",
        "JobName": "ProgC",
        "Environment": "TEST"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "IsDev": "1",
        "JobName": "ProgC",
        "AppID": "372011",
        "ConfigurationID": "1",
        "Environment": "TEST",
        "TESTING": " Yup"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that you're doing this from within Visual Studio.

You need to make sure you're selecting the correct build properties when you run/publish your app.  I'm also going to assume that at present, `ProgC` is selected and needs to be changed.

[image: Build]

That will ensure it's pointing to the right profile and it will then pull your environment variables as you have defined.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  Yeah, nothing I found talked about changing that, having to install Linux Kernels, etc.